# Recursion without arguments and static variables

Tags: recursion, linked-list, parameter-passing

I was asked to write a recursive function to print a singly linked list. But my instructor told me that you can not use static variables or arguments in the function. Is recursion really possible without arguments and static variables?

void recursivePrint() const;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Since `recursivePrint()` is a member function, you merely have to print the value at the head, and then recursively print the rest of the list:

```
void recursivePrint() const {
  if (!head) {
    return;
  }
  std::cout << head->value << " ";
  if (head->next) {
    head->next->recursivePrint();
  }
}
```